# What does { ... } do without any loop, control statement, etc in C?

Tags: c, microcontroller, curly-braces

I've run across some C code targeting TI microcontrollers that looks like this:

```
statement;
statement;

{
    statement;
    {
        statement;
        statement;
    }

    {
        statement;
        statement;
    }
}
```

I'm confused by the use of the `{ ... }` blocks without a loop or control statement or anything. The comments suggest that this is an "atomic subsystem," but I understand the need for nested sets of `{ { ... } }` in that situation.

- Do the curly braces have any meaning here?
- If so, is this meaning inherent to TI's compiler or is it a standard part of C?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593140/dont-understand-this-block-of-codeit-runs-with-no-condition/10593162#10593162

Comment: Thanks Boumbles. Searched for so long, not sure how I missed that. Apple's blocks C extension has made this really hard to Google...

Comment: Why the downvote? It is not a bad question and it has been closed as a dup?